# Optimizing neighbor count function for conway's game of life in C

Tags: c, for-loop, optimization

Having some trouble optimizing a function that returns the number of neighbors of a cell in a Conway's Game of Life implementation. I'm trying to learn C and just get better at coding. I'm not very good at recognizing potential optimizations, and I've spent a lot of time online reading various methods but it's not really clicking for me yet.

Specifically I'm trying to figure out how to unroll this nested for loop in the most efficient way, but each time I try I just make the runtime longer. 
I'm including the function, I don't think any other context is needed. Thanks for any advice you can give!

Here is the code for the `countNeighbors()` function:

```
static int countNeighbors(board b, int x, int y)
{
   int n = 0;

   int x_left = max(0, x-1);
   int x_right = min(HEIGHT, x+2);
   int y_left = max(0, y-1);
   int y_right = min(WIDTH, y+2);

   int xx, yy;
   for (xx = x_left; xx < x_right; ++xx) {
       for (yy = y_left; yy < y_right; ++yy) {
           n += b[xx][yy];
       }
   }

   return n - b[x][y];
}
```

Comment: Is this code actually a performance bottleneck?  How did you demonstrate that it is actually taking up more time in your code than anything else?  Have you checked that you're not calling the function too often?

Comment: How board is defined?

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk: It is almost certainly `int b[HEIGHT][WIDTH];`, but I agree it should be specified — despite the comment that "I don't think any other context is needed".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of declaring board as `b[WIDTH][HEIGHT]` declare it as `b[WIDTH + 2][HEIGHT + 2]`. This gives an extra margin which will have zeros, but it prevents from index out of bounds. So, instead of:

```
 x x
 x x
```

We will have:

```
 0 0 0 0 
 0 x x 0
 0 x x 0
 0 0 0 0
```

`x` denotes used cells, `0` will be unused.

Typical trade off: a bit of memory for speed.

Thanks to that we don't have to call `min` and `max` functions (which have bad for performance `if` statements).

Finally, I would write your function like that:

```
int countNeighborsFast(board b, int x, int y)
{
    int n = 0;
    n += b[x-1][y-1];
    n += b[x][y-1];
    n += b[x+1][y-1];
    n += b[x-1][y];
    n += b[x+1][y];
    n += b[x-1][y+1];
    n += b[x][y+1];
    n += b[x+1][y+1];
    return n;
}
```

### Benchmark (updated)

[Full, working source code](http://pastebin.com/q6nvK1f2).

Thanks to Jongware [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552102/optimizing-neighbor-count-function-for-conways-game-of-life-in-c/30552203#comment-49199080) I added linearization (reducing array's dimensions from 2 to 1) and changing `int` to `char`.

I also made the main loop linear and calculate the returned sum directly, without an intermediate `n` variable.

2D array was 10002 x 10002, 1D had 100040004 elements.

The CPU I have is Pentium Dual-Core T4500 at 2.30 GHz, further details  [here](http://pastebin.com/pdfkx0D0) (output of `cat /prof/cpuinfo`).

Results on default optimization level `O0`:

```
Original: 15.50s
Mine: 10.13s
Linear: 2.51s
LinearAndChars: 2.48s
LinearAndCharsAndLinearLoop: 2.32s
LinearAndCharsAndLinearLoopAndSum: 1.53s
```

That's about 10x faster compared to the original version.

Results on `O2`:

```
Original: 6.42s
Mine: 4.17s
Linear: 0.55s
LinearAndChars: 0.53s
LinearAndCharsAndLinearLoop: 0.42s
LinearAndCharsAndLinearLoopAndSum: 0.44s
```

About 15x faster.

On `O3`:

```
Original: 10.44s
Mine: 1.47s
Linear: 0.26s
LinearAndChars: 0.26s
LinearAndCharsAndLinearLoop: 0.25s
LinearAndCharsAndLinearLoopAndSum: 0.24s
```

About 44x faster.

The last version, `LinearAndCharsAndLinearLoopAndSum` is:

```
typedef char board3[(HEIGHT + 2) * (WIDTH + 2)];

int i;
for (i = WIDTH + 3; i <= (WIDTH + 2) * (HEIGHT + 1) - 2; i++)
    countNeighborsLinearAndCharsAndLinearLoopAndSum(b3, i);

int countNeighborsLinearAndCharsAndLinearLoopAndSum(board3 b, int pos)
{
    return
    b[pos - 1 - (WIDTH + 2)] +
    b[pos     - (WIDTH + 2)] +
    b[pos + 1 - (WIDTH + 2)] +
    b[pos - 1] +
    b[pos + 1] +
    b[pos - 1 + (WIDTH + 2)] +
    b[pos     + (WIDTH + 2)] +
    b[pos + 1 + (WIDTH + 2)];
}
```

Changing `1 + (WIDTH + 2)` to `WIDTH + 3` won't help, because compiler takes care of it anyway (even on `O0` optimization level).

Comment: Size of the grid used to run the benchmarks? 1002 x 1002? 10002 x 10002? Please update the answer with the size of the grid used. It will be also useful knowing your processor as other people could want to do benchmarks also. Thanks.

Comment: Changing the 2-dimensional board to a 1-dimensional array (only a simple cast), and pre-calculating `int linearpos = (WIDTH+2)*y+x;` and adding/subtracting `(WIDTH+2)` for the `y` changes instead, you remove 8 multiplications. That leads to an impressive change of 14.93s (original) to  8.79s (yours) to 1.89s (mine). Changing the board from `int` to `char` makes the difference smaller – "must be caching" in that case.